# How to show a prompt window on setting the cursor on a button with JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, cursor

i want to show a `Prompt Window` while the user set the cursor on a button. I am asking exactelly of how do an action on setting the cursor on a controller like Button, i don't need that `butn.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);` how i can do that and thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [`TextInputDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputDialog.html) ?

Comment: How i can use it please ?

Comment: Do you want to show it when the mouse clicks on the button or when the mouse hovers on the button?

Comment: i want it hover on the button

Comment: Isn't this just a [`Tooltip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `button.setOnMouseEntered` event to show the `TextInputDialog`, wait for the user input and then use it.

Here is a small example, which shows a `TextInputDialog` and prints the data entered by the user.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputDialog;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Optional;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        StackPane box = new StackPane();
        Button button = new Button("Hover on me !!!");
        TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog("Itachi");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Text Input Dialog");
        dialog.setContentText("Please enter your name:");
        button.setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
            if(!dialog.isShowing()) {
                Optional<String> result = dialog.showAndWait();
                result.ifPresent(name -> System.out.println("Your name: " + name));
            }
        });
        box.getChildren().add(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 200, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```